# How to set the android:export to false in the package manifest file

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

I build the app using flutter, give the .apk file to penetration testing.How resolve these issues?

i can't see these Service and Broadcast Receiver in the android manifest file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find android:exported=true in AndroidManifested.xml you just need to goto :

```
<manifest>
   ...
  <application>
       ...
     <activity>
         android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity" //find the MainActivity activity
         android:exported="true" //here it is
         ...
     </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```